# How to Version control stored procedures using TortoiseCVS

Tags: sql-server

I need to version control the stored procedures I create on SQL Server Management Studio 2008. How do I configure TortoiseCVS as an external tool for source control on SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

If SSMS is anything like visual studio! The only native support for source control plugins are by default visual source safe and perforce? To support anything else would involve an external plugin on the free market OR to develop your own plugin.

Comment: The question specifically asks about configuring TortoiseCVS as **an external tool**, so "native support" doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm product manager for SQL Source Control, which provides SSMS integration to various source control systems. CVS isn't supported out of the box but it *might* be possible as we do provide a way of letting you specify your own command lines by modifying a config file in the following folder:

%AppData%\Local\Red Gate\SQL Source Control 3\CommandLineHooks\

If you struggle with this please contact Red Gate support (support@red-gate.com). For more information about SQL Source Control, visit:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/